# Change pen thickness in teechart for php

Tags: php, html, builder, teechart

I'm using Embarcadero's HTML5 builder (php) and TeeChart to draw graphs. Works beautifully for most parts. The TeeChart documentation for php is however pretty sparse to say at least - lots of trial and errors. I can't find a way to set the pen thickness for a line graph. Nothing on Google. Anyone out there who knows?

Also, if one uses a Bar graph, one would think following code snippet should disable the annotating marks over each bar:

```
$series1=$this->Chart2->addSeries(new TeeBar($this));
$series1->Marks->Visible = false;
```

It doesn't. `Marks->Visible` doesn't do anything. The default marks are still displayed.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using [TeeChart for PHP](https://www.steema.com/teechart/php) in HTML5 Builder XE3:**

> I can't find a way to set the pen thickness for a line graph. Nothing
>   on Google. Anyone out there who knows?

If you take the features demo included with the installation as reference, you'll find the Line2D example in it. After creating the chart:

```
$chart = new TChart(500,300);
```

The Line series are added and populated:

```
$line1=new Line($chart->getChart());  
$data = Array(10,50,25,175,125,200,175);
$line1->addArray($data);

$line2=new Line($chart->getChart());  
$line2->addXY(0,10);
$line2->addXY(1,15);
$line2->addXY(2,20);
$line2->addXY(3,25);                                       
$line2->addXY(10,30);

$line3=new Line($chart->getChart());  
$data = Array(200,175,175,100,65,110,90);
$line3->addArray($data);
```

Then, to make them wider, you can just:

```
$line1->getLinePen()->setWidth(2);
$line2->getLinePen()->setWidth(2);
$line3->getLinePen()->setWidth(2);
```

Or you could use the foreach loop already present:

```
foreach ($chart->getSeries() as $serie) {
  //...

  $serie->getLinePen()->setWidth(2);
}
```

---

> Also, if one uses a Bar graph, one would think following code snippet
>   should disable the annotating marks over each bar:
>
> ```
> $series1=$this->Chart2->addSeries(new TeeBar($this));
> $series1->Marks->Visible = false;
> ```
>
> Tt doesn't. Marks->Visible doesn't do anything. The default marks are still displayed.

Take a look at the Bar series example. It starts like this:

```
$chart1 = new TChart(500,300);

$chart1->getChart()->getHeader()->setText("Bar Style");
$chart1->getChart()->getAspect()->setChart3DPercent(30);

$bar=new Bar($chart1->getChart());
$chart1->getChart()->getSeries(0)->setColorEach(true);
$chart1->getChart()->getSeries(0)->fillSampleValues(10);
```

And you can see the marks in the first Bar chart. But adding the following to the above seems to hide the marks as expected for me here:

```
$chart1->getChart()->getSeries(0)->getMarks()->setVisible(false);
```

The same could be done just like this:

```
$bar->getMarks()->setVisible(false);
```

---

**If you are using [TeeChart HTML5/JavaScript](https://www.steema.com/teechart/html5) in HTML5 Builder XE3:**

> I can't find a way to set the pen thickness for a line graph. Nothing
>   on Google. Anyone out there who knows?

You can do it through the `format.stroke.size` property, as follows:

```
var Chart1;

function draw() {
  Chart1=new Tee.Chart("canvas1");

  line1=Chart1.addSeries(new Tee.Line());
  line1.addRandom(25);
  line1.format.stroke.size=2;

  line2=Chart1.addSeries(new Tee.Line());
  line2.addRandom(25);

  Chart1.draw();
}
```

---

> Also, if one uses a Bar graph, one would think following code snippet
>   should disable the annotating marks over each bar:
>
> ```
> $series1=$this->Chart2->addSeries(new TeeBar($this));
> $series1->Marks->Visible = false;
> ```
>
> Tt doesn't. Marks->Visible doesn't do anything. The default marks are
>   still displayed.

This seems to work as expected for me here:

```
var Chart1;

function draw() {
  Chart1=new Tee.Chart("canvas1");

  bar1=Chart1.addSeries(new Tee.Bar());
  bar1.addRandom(6);
  bar1.marks.visible=false;

  bar2=Chart1.addSeries(new Tee.Bar());
  bar2.addRandom(6);

  Chart1.draw();
}
```

Comment: Tks Yeray. It seems however that the TeeChart shipped with Embarcadero's RAD Studio XE3 for HTML5 builder is somewhat limited. When I run the code with $line1->getLinePen()->setWidth(2);

Comment: Again: Tks Yeray. It seems however that the TeeChart shipped with Embarcadero's RAD Studio XE3 for HTML5 builder is somewhat limited. When I run the code with $line1->getLinePen()->setWidth(2); I get following error: Fatal error: Call to a member function getMarks() on a non-object in C:\Users\Magnus B\Documents\HTML5 Builder\Projects\LS_user\MainUnit.php on line 97. Same error occurs if I disables Marks with getMarks

Comment: I thought you were using TeeChart for PHP instead of TeeChart HTML5. I've edited the answer with a second part. I hope it helps!